# group_rolling per group in polars

Tags: window-functions, python-polars

Let's say I have the following df:

```
example_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
    "date": pl.date_range(low=date(2022, 1, 1), high=date(2022, 1, 30), interval="1d"),
    "group": ["A", "B", "C"]*10,
    'total': np.random.randint(100, size=30)
    }
)
```

Now I want to sum the total per group, in a time window of 5 days. Something like combining groupby with groupby_rolling.

I wonder if there more elegant and efficient way to do it than the following code:

```
df_list = []

for table_group in example_df['group'].unique():
    temp_df = (
        example_df
        .filter(pl.col('group')==table_group)
        .sort('date')
        .groupby_rolling('date', period='5d')
        .agg(pl.col('total').sum().prefix('roll_'))
    )
    
    temp_df2 = (
        example_df
        .filter(pl.col('group')==table_group)
        .sort('date')
        .select([
            pl.all(),
            temp_df.get_column('roll_total')
            ])
    )
    df_list.append(temp_df2)

pl.concat(df_list)
```

My main issue is that I have millions of rows and over 10,000 groups(and more than 1 column that I want to sum)...
So this code is not so elegant and consumes more memory than I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the piece you're missing is the [`by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling.html) parameter.

This allows you to specify grouping.

```
(df.groupby_rolling(index_column="date", by="group", period="5d")
   .agg(
      pl.col("total").last(),
      roll_total = pl.sum("total")))
```

```
shape: (30, 4)
┌───────┬────────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ date       ┆ total ┆ roll_total │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str   ┆ date       ┆ i64   ┆ i64        │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 96    ┆ 96         │
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-04 ┆ 16    ┆ 112        │
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-07 ┆ 17    ┆ 33         │
│ A     ┆ 2022-01-10 ┆ 4     ┆ 21         │
│ …     ┆ …          ┆ …     ┆ …          │
│ C     ┆ 2022-01-21 ┆ 17    ┆ 78         │
│ C     ┆ 2022-01-24 ┆ 84    ┆ 101        │
│ C     ┆ 2022-01-27 ┆ 78    ┆ 162        │
│ C     ┆ 2022-01-30 ┆ 54    ┆ 132        │
└───────┴────────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```